# Adding web font from Fonts.com

Tags: 7, theming

I made a test.html file to test web fonts bought on Fonts.com.

```
@import url("http://fast.fonts.com/cssapi/3bcaa9a7-xxxx...xxxx.css");
```

This worked without any problem. But when I add this to my global.css file in my Drupal Template, it doesn't work. Other things from global.css are all ok... So the file gets loaded.

Any other simple way to do this without the use of a module?

Comment: is your global.css used ? //check the source code ..

Comment: Yes, all other stuff I put in global.css is working, without any problem. It seems like the @import doesn't work...

Comment: and you're applying your font to some styles too ?

Comment: Yes:

@import url("http://fast.fonts.com/cssapi/xxx.css");

BODY {
background-color: #000e19;
color: white;
font-family:'Frutiger Neue W01 Book';
}

H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6 {
font-family:'Cachet W01 Book'; 
}

Comment: try to get it work with an inspector, maybe you'll find the issue ..

Comment: What's an "inspector"? :o

Comment: fe. in chrome, hit the right mouse button and Inspect Element - you can adapt your site on the fly

Comment: Oh yes, tried that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my god... It had to be something stupid. This was the sollution:

On Fonts.com go to "Manage Web Fonts", and add a domain. The HTML I tested was on my localhost, the Drupal wasn't.

Glad I found the answer when I was walking outside...

Comment: told ya ;) ...-